# Is it possible to prerender before redirect?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, parameters, metadata, prerender

I'm utilizing prerender.io service to prerender my React app.
In the app I have a transitional page to send to the prerender.io parametrised metadata and then redirect to the app's main page.

The problem is that it seems that the service prerenders the destination page (the app's main page) with its metadata instead of transitional one.

Question: how to prerender transitional page with its metadata?

Comment: The only way I found so far by experiments is setting redirection timeout to 5 seconds or more (less than that hasn't worked for me).

Comment: Hi Oleg! Could you send us an example of a URL where you are running into these issues? We'd be happy to take a look and see what we can suggest! support@prerender.io

Comment: Hi @Prerender.io. I've sent an email to support@prerender.io with example details on the issue. Going to duplicate it here for better understanding of the question for other readers.

Comment: Example of link: http://stage.eurekly.com/incentive-to-share/masters.shifus.1
As mentioned, a solution is found (not fully satisfying one thought) which is to redirect in 5 second (currently implemented for the link).
The page purpose is to get metadata for sharing on facebook with a tutor name as a parameter (tutor name is determined by the last part in the url, so in the given example by masters.shifus.1).
The desired result would be to redirect immediately, that shared link would lead to destination page, but metadata would be taken from the page from which redirection happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So with the javascript redirect happening immediately, the Prerender server is thinking the page is still loading so it does not check the meta tags until after the javascript redirect is complete.

The best solution here is to delay the javascript redirect for ~5 seconds for a Prerender browser but to allow the javascript redirect to happen immediately for a normal user.

Comment: To complete the answer:
redirection delay for Prerender is implemented as
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('prerender') >= 0) waitTime = 5000